# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i x \beta}}{(x^2+c)^{1/2}} dx $

Tags: integration

I try to integrate

I tried to integrate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i x \beta}} {(x^2+c)^{1/2}}\,\, dx $$ but failed. Does anybody know a way, e.g. by substitution or residue theorem?

Comment: What did you try to do for a first step?

Comment: It boils down to $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx = K_0(|a|) $$ with $K_0$ being a modified Bessel function of the second kind.